# Getting [object: Promise] instead of the value itself

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch, javascript-objects

It's the first time I use promises in JavaScript so I apologise in advance if this is a dumb question. I need to fetch a field from an API call and use it in another function. This is my code:

```
async function getComposerName() {

  try {
    let composerID = document.querySelectorAll('#addCompositionFromPerformanceForm select')[0].value
    let url = 'http://151.236.37.122/api/profiles/' + composerID + '/?format=json';
    let response = await fetch(url);

    let composition = await response.json(); // read response body and parse as JSON

    console.log(composition['user']); // This correctly returns the name of the composer in the console at the end of addComposition() is run.

    let ComposerName = composition['user'] // this is a valid value when run in the browser's console

    return ComposerName;
}
  catch(error){
    console.log('error')
  }
}


function full_title(){

  var title = document.querySelectorAll('#addCompositionFromPerformanceForm input')[1].value

  let fullTitle = title + ', by ' + getComposerName()

  return fullTitle;
}


function addComposition (oFormElement) {

  if ( confirm("Are you sure you wish to add " + full_title() + " to the database?") == false ) {
       return false ;
    } else {
[other stuff]
```

When I call the `addComposition()` function (it's a form submit) I get the alert message with this text:

```
Are you sure you wish to add My Title, by [object Promise] to the database?
```

Of course I'd like to see the composer's name instead of `[object Promise]`. The funny thing is that when I click on 'cancel' I see the composer's name popping up in the console log, which means, I suppose, that the promise gets fulfilled after the whole code in `addComposition()` is run. Am I right? How do I get the composer's name in my alert message?

Thanks.

Comment: [`async` function return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value): _"**A `Promise`** which will be resolved with the value returned by the `async` function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the `async` function."_

Comment: Your composer check is asynchronous. You cannot use its result synchronously, because it hasn't provided that result yet.

Comment: Thank you both. The thing is that I need to fetch the composer's name from my API and then use it in my code. If I just open an ajax call within my code and get it from there, then that value is not available outside the ajax call. Am I right?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I still don't understand though Even adding   let full_title = title + ', by ' + (await getComposerName();
    return composer
  })() doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @HBMCS - In the code you have above, that would be a syntax error, because you can only use `await` in an `async` function and the function that code (or rather, the code setting `fullTitle`) is in isn't `async`. But you're on the right track: If **all** of the functions involved were `async` functions, you could do that. Just be sure that whatever's calling the entry point to that call chain understands that what it gets back is a promise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I meant   let full_title = title + ', by ' + (async function(){
    let composer = await getComposerName();
    return composer
    console.log(composer);
  })()

This still returns object Promise. I've even added 'async' before all my functions as you suggested, and I still get the object thing. Sigh.

Comment: @HBMCS - Again, `async` functions return promises. You can't use the result of calling an `async` function synchronously. All you've done there is add another `async` wrapper around it, but not fundamentally changed anything.